# Relative path for require module in linux server error: Cannot find module

Tags: node.js

I have a problem in deploying my node.js application on Ubuntu server. The version of node.js is 12.13.0

I develop my app in Windows and use relative path in `require` such as:

```
const { Response } = require("../lib/response");
```

It works locally but on the server I have this error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module '../lib/response'
Require stack:
- /project/api/routes/category.js
- /project/api/router.js
- /project/api/app.js
- /project/api/bin/www
```

I Google this problem for 24 hours.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: add `my server node version is v12.16.3 my windows node version is:` to your question. Always respond to questions by improving your question.

Comment: Did you check uppercase/lowercase of directory name?

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be to used to docker for local development with same environment as of production.
For more help 
Also, can u tell us the nodejs version on your server and on your local machine.

Comment: i told you. 
my server node s version is v12.16.3
my windows node version is  v12.13.0

Comment: i won't to use docker

Comment: Maybe the folder name would differ as in Linux it considers case sensitivity. Just show us the folder structure also It would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

simple of my folder structure

```
/project
___/api
______/lib
______/router
______/database
______/www
```

i use relative path for require modules in windows and it works! but in linux server have error. it says you must to use absolute path for require modules

in another projects i use relative path in both os and i haven't any errors for path
but in this project i got this error

and i reinstall my server os but not working